# No hace bien la comparacion de fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un query donde me saca que mi fecha de inicio es `'2017-06-12'` y al compararla me sale que es menor a `'2017-06-04'`, ¿qué podrá ser?

El query es el siguiente:

```
select fecha_inicio
      ,month(fecha_inicio) as mes
      ,day(fecha_inicio)
      ,if(fecha_inicio < '2017-06-04', 'MENOR', 'MAYOR') as es
  from ventas
 where numero_cuenta in ('B1557','F3622')
 order by numero_cuenta
```

Si alguien me pudiera orientar se lo agradecería, los campos que uso son tipo `date`.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar mayor información sobre la estructura de tu tabla, con datos que permitan reproducir el error? De la forma que está formulada la pregunta, no es posible encontrar dónde se genera tu problema

Comment: Hola mariano si mis datos originales eran de fox los exporte a dbase para de access pasarlos a mysql lo cual me genero una tabla con campo tipo varchar y de ahi los inserte en mi tabla  nueva en un campo tipo date ycon el formato 'YYYY-mm-dd'  y al momento de hacer incluso la comparacion directa '2017-06-12'<'2017-06-04' me trae resultado que este 12 es menor al 4 de junio :(

Comment: Estoy seguro de que el error viene por ahí: o una columna con el tipo incorrecto, o un dato mal convertido... Sin embargo, esta pregunta es imposible de responder si no podemos ver la estructura completa de la tabla con datos para poder reproducirlo. Espero que puedas [edit] la pregunta con esta información.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma funciona:

```
SELECT 
    fecha_inicio, 
    CASE 
      WHEN fecha_inicio < '2017-06-04' THEN 'MENOR'
      WHEN fecha_inicio = '2017-06-04' THEN 'IGUAL'
      ELSE 'MAYOR'
    END as 'es'
FROM prueba_fechas;
```

Aunque me preguntaba: ¿qué pasa si son iguales?

Por eso ves que he agregado esto: `WHEN fecha_inicio = '2017-06-04' THEN 'IGUAL'` por si te interesa presentar la igualdad aparte, si no te interesa puedes eliminar esta línea

> ***Nota***: Cuida de no tener tus fechas **formateadas** en la tabla, lo cual sería un grave error y te traería problemas a la hora de comparar
>   o calcular datos.

**Ejemplo completo**

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NRT10071)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prueba_fechas
    (`fecha_inicio` date)
;
/*  
INSERT INTO prueba_fechas
    (`fecha_inicio`)
VALUES
    ('2017-06-01'),
    ('2017-06-02'),
    ('2017-06-03'),
    ('2017-06-04'),
    ('2017-06-05'),
    ('2017-06-06')
;

*/

SELECT 
    fecha_inicio, 
    CASE 
      WHEN fecha_inicio < '2017-06-04' THEN 'MENOR'
      WHEN fecha_inicio = '2017-06-04' THEN 'IGUAL'
      ELSE 'MAYOR'
    END as 'es'
FROM prueba_fechas;
```

**resultado**

```
    fecha_inicio           es
1   01.06.2017 00:00:00    MENOR
2   02.06.2017 00:00:00    MENOR
3   03.06.2017 00:00:00    MENOR
4   04.06.2017 00:00:00    IGUAL
5   05.06.2017 00:00:00    MAYOR
6   06.06.2017 00:00:00    MAYOR
```

Comment: gracias por contestar  sabes lo probe pero sigue en lo mismo lo que me llama la atención es que comentas cuide " fechas formateadas" a que te refieres con eso? quiza por ahi este mi error

Comment: @kany Si al crear la tabla has declarado la columna `fecha_inicio` del tipo `date` y al introducir la fecha lo  has hecho así: `yyyy-mm-dd`, o sea, primero las 4 cifras del año, luego las 2 cifras del mes, y finalmente las dos cifras del día , no debería darte problema alguno. A eso me refiero.

Comment: hola si de hecho asi lo hice por eso no entiendo porque no hace la comparacion bien

Comment: lo unico que se es que mi tabla original de datos si estaba el campo varchar y de ahi los inserte en mi nueva tabla que ya el campo si era tipo fecha

Comment: @kany Sería importante que verifiques **como están insertados los datos directamente en la columna de la tabla**, si están por ejemplo así: `04062017`, o así `06042017`  o  `20170604` o `04-06-2017`, o así `06-04-2017`  o  `2017-06-04` . Me parece que por ahí anda el asunto, porque como has visto, si los datos estuviesen bien insertados y si son del tipo fecha, no hay motivo para que no funcione.

Comment: hola si esta bien insertados mi formato 2017-06-10 es decir  yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @kany como has visto en las pruebas el código funcionaría si tus datos estuviesen bien. Por lo tanto debe haber de algún error en tus datos o simplemente no existen datos que cumplan los criterios que quieres comparar.

Answer (score 0):

En vez del **if** en el select de tu sentencia SQL, deberías cambiarlo por un **CASE** de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT fecha_inicio
    ,MONTH(fecha_inicio) as mes
    ,DAY(fecha_inicio) as dia
    ,CASE 
        WHEN fecha_inicio < '20170604' THEN 'MENOR' ELSE 'MAYOR'
    END as es
FROM ventas
WHERE numero_cuenta in ('B1557','F3622')
ORDER BY numero_cuenta
```

Nota la forma en que comparo la fecha, si el campo **fecha_inicio** es del tipo **date**, con ello ya no deberías presentar problemas en tu consulta, saludos.

Comment: Hola Rostan gracias por responder lo probe así  como me dices y me sigue dando el mismo resultado que las dos fechas son menores incluso puse directamente la fecha y sigue iguañ :(

Comment: Dale, entonce por favor edita tu pregunta y sube un capture de lo que te esta devolviendo SQL.

Comment: de hecho ahora me sale que las dos fechas son mayores en este caso fecha 1 es 20170612 que si es mayor y la fecha2 es 20170215 y dice que tambien es mayor a 20170604

Comment: LISTO  lo resolvi cree un nuevo campo tipo fecha y volvi a insertar la fecha y funciono gracias a todos los que contestaron

Comment: congratz, un gusto haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo unicamente en tu codigo sql, deberia funcionarte. Si es asi, en lugar de los prints declaras la columna y ya.

```
if('2017-06-12' < '2017-06-04')
    print   'MENOR'
else
    print   'MAYOR'
```

Comment: hola gracias por contestar tambien lo hice y me sigue dando el mismo resultado no se me ocurre mas